# Blazor Server SignarlR HubConnection StartAsync throws error

Tags: c#, signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-5

When the hub hits the `StartAsync()` line it throws this error:

`JsonReaderException: '<' is an invalid start of a value.`

My guess is the `HubConnection` is getting HTML instead of JSON. But what is the html? How can I see what the content is that's causing the `HubConnection` to fail on `StartAsync()`?

Here's the full code that's running. I can see the access token so I know it's not empty and I know it's valid because I can visit other `[Authorized]` pages.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    //create the hub with the url and a token
    //configure logging to get better errors
    hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(
        NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/chathub"), options =>
        {
            options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(TokenProvider.AccessToken);
        })
    .ConfigureLogging(logging => {
        logging.AddFilter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR", LogLevel.Debug);
    )
    .Build();


    //create a listener for any incoming messages
    hubConnection.On<ChatMessage>("ReceiveMessage", (message) =>
    {
        ChatMessages.Add(message);
        StateHasChanged();
    });

    //start the hub and away we go
    await hubConnection.StartAsync();
}
```

Here is the Hub

```
namespace territory_lords.Hubs
{
    [Authorize]
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(ChatMessage chatMessage)
        {
            //just send it to the people who aren't us. We already know about it
            await Clients.Others.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", chatMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Configure from Startup

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseResponseCompression();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();


        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {

            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you include the definition of your Hub?

Comment: @AmalK I think I added what you're asking for. This is my first foray into SignalR so I don't really know much about it at all.

Comment: Did you add `endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub")` to the `Configure()` method of `Startup.cs`?

Comment: There is a possibility that this has something to do with authentication. See this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20725273/signalr-net-client-unexpected-character-encountered-while-parsing-value). However, it is about the older ASP.NET but may still help.

Comment: @AmalK I added in the Configure function of my Startup

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am having this exact issue

Comment: @EyeSeeSharp I never did figure it out. I simply turned allow anonymous on my hubs, which probably isn't ok in a production env but I'm just building to learn so I didn't want this to hold me back any longer

Answer (score 0):

This is an awfully worded authentication error. I wish SignalR had awareness of what it was doing so it could tell you what authentication was sent and why the response was unexpected.

Your `AddAuthentication` is blank and I'm not sure which method you want to use. I will show an example that leverages negotiation, which will allow local AD authentication with the local user account. This is good for on premise development. If you're doing cloud then you need to be passing AzureAD token which is a whole other can of worms.

I turned on some more verbose logging for SignalR and it was talking about negotiation.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection|Failed to start connection. Error getting negotiation response from <!hub name!>

So I installed a NuGet package in my hub project:
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate`

Then I added a service configuration to allow negotiation in my hub Startup:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddNegotiate();
```

Now when the client asks for negotiation, they can magically pass the local user and authenticate using your local domain.

Related reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio